# Append to array except 0th index in smarty

Tags: smarty

Is there any smarty function to append element to the array except o index ?

e.g.

```
array = ('test 1', 'test 2', 'test 3');
```

Where I want 'test 2' at 0th position and o/p should be

```
array = ('test 2', 'test 1', 'test 3');
```

Thanks in advance of any suggestion.

Comment: you mean you want to prepend it?

Comment: humm yes. i want matching element should be first element in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
{assign var=element $array[1]}
{$array[1]|unset}
{$array|array_unshift:$element}
```